# How to insert slide numbers using Amsterdam theme?

Tags: beamer, themes

How to insert slide numbers using Amsterdam theme?

When I use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}` it works but also deletes the last part of the slides.

Comment: `Amsterdam` is not part of the standard beamer package. Can you please add a link to the theme?

Comment: \usetheme{Amsterdam}

Comment: Yes, but this only works if the theme is installed. And as it's not part of the standard themes which ship with `texlive` I am asking you where to find it.

Comment: is the first one in this link... https://latex.simon04.net/

Answer (score 3):

The `Amsterdam` theme uses the `authortitle` footline from the `miniframes` other theme. The additional lines to insert the framenumbers are marked with `% NEW` in the following.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{amsterdam}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \hfill%
    {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
    \hfill% NEW
    {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber}% NEW
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\author{Einstein}
\title{Cool Stuff}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In the current development version of beamer (and probably included in released versions starting with v. 3.50) this answer can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{amsterdam}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\author{Einstein}
\title{Cool Stuff}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wrote this and the number of each slide was located down and in the middle:                  \usetheme{Amsterdam}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

Comment: @VanessaQuiñones Yes?